# generics with context to wild cards

Tags: java, generics

In an interview with regard to generics the interviewer ask a question that there are two list,one list is of String type (that is one arraylist is of string type) and we add some strings in it, now create the second array list which will be of type the the first list you created, means the second ararylist will accept the objects type of first list created he give me the hint that it could be achieve through generics , please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. Please clarify.

Comment: two list(arraylist) are there , first one is of type string and second list should accept the objects of type first arraylist, please advise how to achieve this with generics itself.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess from your description,

```
List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();

public <T> List<T> createSecondList(List<T> firstList)
{
   return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is what he asked,

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```