# generics with different approach

Tags: java, generics

In an interview with regard to generics the interviewer ask a question that there are two list,one list is of String type (that is one arraylist is of string type) and we add some strings in it, now create the second array list which will be of type the the first list you created , Now the possible solution was as shown below..

```
List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();

public <T> List<T> createSecondList(List<T> firstList)
{
   return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

my query was can we express this in the below way also please advise.

```
List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
 <T> List<T> createSecondList = new ArrayList(List<T> firstList);
```

Comment: are you asking about how to call the generified method or how else we can represent it?

Comment: The first approach is the way to do it. Your second example (if it compiled) is not very useful: when you call it you do know the type of the original list so you don't need generics.

Answer (score 5):

No.

This line:

```
<T> List<T> createSecondList = new ArrayList(List<T> firstList);
```

Is not valid Java code, its kind of half way between a method declaration and a variable declaration and instantiation..

To create the second list...

```
List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> secondList = createSecondList(firstList);
```

Comment: @cowls "the answer at the start of the post" is actually the answer to the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289585/generics-with-context-to-wild-cards

Answer (score 0):

1> `List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();` //this is first type
2> `List<List<String>> list2 =  new ArrayList<List<String>>();` //this is second type which is including first list type